# Can Postgres restrict usage of the SET and SHOW commands?

Tags: postgresql, permissions

Is it possible to restrict a role from being able to set arbitrary session variables, or from being able to view them?

```
select current_setting('x');

show x;
```

Even after I've switched roles to a one with lesser permissions, I'm able to run both of the above and retrieve a value I might want hidden from that role. I think that it might be possible to lock down the first statement (that's a built-in function, is it not?), but I can't find anything in the documentation about the latter statement concerning grants or permissions.

Comment: If you want session specific "variables", you could use a temp table (with `on commit preserve rows`)

Answer (score 0):

There are no session parameters in PostgreSQL; `SET` changes the value of a global parameter for the current session.  If you use it to set a custom parameter (with a name containing `.`) that does not yet exist, a so-called *placeholder parameter* is created. There is no way to restrict permissions to view such a placeholder parameter.

What you can do is write a module in C that creates a real parameter. That module has to have a `_PG_init` function that calls `DefineCustomStringVariable` (if it is a string you want). That module would then be added to `shared_preload_libraries`, so that the parameter is defined when the server starts.

Such a parameter can be defined as `GUC_SUPERUSER_ONLY`, which means that only a superuser (or a member of the `pg_read_all_settings` role) can see its value.